# Service wont stop even after app is detroyed

Tags: android

I am building a toast every 5 sec using some sample found.
The code works ok, but the service wont stop even i stopped the app.
Can anyone point out what is wrong?

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public static final long INTERVAL=5000;//variable to execute services every 5 second
private Handler mHandler=new Handler(); // run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Timer mTimer=null; // timer handling
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported Operation");
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // cancel if service is  already existed
    if(mTimer!=null)
        mTimer.cancel();
    else
        mTimer=new Timer(); // recreate new timer
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(),0,INTERVAL);// schedule task
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "In Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//display toast when method called
    mTimer.cancel();//cancel the timer

}
//inner class of TimeDisplayTimerTask
private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // display toast at every 5second
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notify", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

I keep receiving the toast Notify even the app had been closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**add onTaskRemoved() method in your MyService,like this**

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    stopSelf();///its will stop service
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

Comment: the Notice still on going

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity `onStop()` you should call `stopService(new Intent(context,YourService.class));` in order to stop your service

Comment: do you mean on top of the onDestroy, i should add another onStop()?
Or i should just substitute the on detroy with onstop?